# SQL Query involving Location and Time

Tags: sql, hive

Hi i'm looking for help in an SQL query I am trying to produce. I'm trying to check the most popular hours of user requests from different locations.

Every time I include Location in the query I get errors and the query won't work...I can't figure out how to put everything together. Can anyone suggest anything?

So far, I have:

```
SELECT HOUR(Time), COUNT(HOUR(Time))
FROM cloudfront_logs 
WHERE DateLog BETWEEN '2014-07-05' AND '2014-08-05' 
GROUP BY HOUR(Time);
```

Which gives me the time of requests(in hour intervals) and the number of requests per hour. The time is given in military style(14:00, 15:00, 20:00).

```
14 2000       (2000 requests during 2-3pm)
15 998        (998 requests during 3-4pm)
20 1998       (1998 requests during 8-9pm)
```

Here is the table I am querying:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cloudfront_logs (
  DateLog DATE,
  Time STRING,
  Location STRING,
  Bytes INT,
  RequestIP STRING,
  Method STRING,
  Host STRING,
  Uri STRING,
  Status INT,
  Referrer STRING,
  OS STRING,
  Browser STRING,
  BrowserVersion STRING
```

Comment: Post your errors as well... below your code and use ">" for the yellowboxing around errors. Make your code a minimalist working example!

Comment: If you include Location in the select, then it should also be included in `group by`

Comment: Thanks so much Kaushik! And yeah for the future I will make sure to follow your tips, cheers ZF007.